# Foursquare Restaurant API

Tags: foursquare

Recently [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/) announced [Restaurants menu details](http://mashable.com/2012/01/19/foursquare-menus/.).

Is there any developer API available which on check in to FourSquare will return the menu details as well?

Comment: You should subscribe to the developer announcement-only mailing list for announcements about API changes. See https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/support for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official FourSquare [blog](http://blog.foursquare.com/2012/01/18/find-what-you%E2%80%99re-craving-and-check-out-the-menu-too/) says we can get it via the API

And the API endpoint is [venues/[id]/menu](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/menu)